# Amplifier noise output against source resistance

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

I’m doing an experiment measuring the noise output of a two stage amplifier with different source resistances.

I’ve found results for a range of resistances. I have plotted these results noise output in dB against source resistance on a log-linear graph (resistance plotted logarithmically.) I get an S shape.

[image]

I’m struggling to fully explain this shape.  With the noise model I have the noise would continue increasing at higher resistances.

Why does it start to flatten out? The amplifier is nowhere near saturation.

Comment: Are you considering just Johnson noise, or shot noise too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *with the noise model I have the noise would continue increasing at higher resistances , why does it start to flatten out?*

The problem is that you are assuming your 2 stage amplifier has infinite input impedance. It clearly doesn't and therefore the finite input impedance value will limit the maximum thermal noise. Making your source resistance even bigger is not going to change this because, in effect, that source resistance is in parallel with the amplifier's input impedance. You'll reach a point where increasing the source resistance does not affect the noise and that is what you see.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense :) .

Answer (score 0):

Besides the nice answer that has been given already, there are other possibilities, having to do with other things that might need to be added to your noise model. Is your source really just a resistor at the frequencies where you are making the noise measurement?  Could it have significant stray capacitance? Are there bias currents coming out of the input of your amplifier, so that it’s operating point depends on the input resistance? Does the amplifier have feedback to the input? In that case the gain may also depend on source impedance.